# How to detect e-mail address and update column?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to detect a certain part of an e-mail address.
For example, the e-mail address is dummy@green.com in column E. I need to detect @green.com or just green then fill green-team in column I.

Something like:

```vb
Cells.Replace What:="@green.com", Replacement:="green", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But it should not replace @green.com but add the green-team inside column I.

Comment: at = add (spelling fault at my side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it assumes the cells you want to look at in column e are selected.

```
Sub emails()

Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In Selection

If InStr(cel.Value, "@green.com") > 0 Then

cel.Offset(, 4).Value = "green-team"

End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't do anything for me :O

Comment: Oh wait it works hehe, sorry I made a mistake to change column E to F do I just adjust the cel.Offset?